# How to send data from BroadcastReceiver to an Activity in android?

Tags: android

I am writing an application to listen the `SMS inbox` in Android with one `Activity` and one `BroadcastReceiver`.
Once the SMS comes the Receiver is showing Alert message...
But i want to send the message information from Receiver to Activity.
I don't know how to achieve this.
Anybody knows it please help me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am writing an application to listen
>   the SMS inbox in android with one
>   activity and one BroadcastReceiver.

[Please do not do this](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/14/code-pollution-reaching-past-the-sdk/). This is not part of the Android SDK. Your application will break on some phones. Your application may break in future editions of Android.

But i want to send the message information from Receiver to Activity.

Send another broadcast `Intent`, this one a private one for use within your own application, where the `Activity` has registered a `BroadcastReceiver` (via `registerReceiver()`) for your private `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 'extras' to the [`Intent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) you use to start the `Activity` using the [`putExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra) methods and retrieve the values using the [`getExtras`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) method.

This mechanism should be used to pass small (meta-, or parameter-like) data to activities. For bigger data structures it is common to pass an `Uri` that identifies the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response.And i tried with the Intent stuff , but it is not working for me.Can you please give some code snippet.