# onReceive is never getting call!

Tags: java, android, sms

onReceive is never getting call!! I had this working and I made some changes and now I been working on this for 5 hours and dont know what my onReceive is not getting called as I do a SMS to it!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG,"onCreate");

        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onReceive");

                if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"in getAction()");

                }

            }
        }, new IntentFilter(RECEIVE_SMS));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Anonymous Classes for your BroadCastReceiver, I think you should define a proper class (package name+class name)and extend it from BroadCastReceiver

In addition, you have to register your BroadcastReceiver in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: yes. 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

Comment: i changed it to try to get the following working http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done

Answer (score 0):

The proper intent to register for is `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`. `RECEIVE_SMS` is from android.persmission, which, incidentally, you'll need to make sure is added to your permissions list in the manifest.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />