# SMS Popup: AlertDialog does not show as I get a SMS message

Tags: android, sms, android-alertdialog

I see a lot of applications that do SMS popups. Why can't I get my app working? If a SMS message comes in, I would like it to popup on the screen.

Here's my code:

```
public class NotifySMSReceived extends Activity 
{

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "SMSReceiver";

    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID_RECEIVED = 0x1221;

    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);

        this.registerReceiver(mReceivedSMSReceiver, filter);

    }


    private void displayAlert()

    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?").setCancelable(

                false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceivedSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (ACTION.equals(action)) 
            {
                //your SMS processing code
                displayAlert();
            }
        }
    };    
}
```

Comment: There are allot of moving parts to get a popup to display when a new SMS Message is received. Can you post your Android Manifest as well as this is a huge part in how it all works.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem here is with context object. From,

> onReceive(Context **context**, Intent intent)

You should pass **context** received in onRecive to like..

> private void displayAlert(Context **context**)

and then, 
change ,

> AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

**TO**

> AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(**context**);

now it should work.hope this helps.

Cheers.

Comment: i made the changes the AlertDialog still dont popup the Toast does

Comment: have you passed context of receiver in alertdialog ? if so then it should work. post error log if any.

Comment: Toast is displayed because it is displayed as system overlay. AlertDialog is displayed only if your application is brought to the foreground when SMS arrives. I checked and I see AlertDialog, but only when I navigate to my application. If you want to force displaying something as overlay over whatever is on the screen, it is not user friendly but is doable.

Comment: try Zelimir but I am trying to make a app like SMS pop.  how did he get it working??