# How do you use an alert dialog box in a broadcast receiver in android?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

So I have a Broadcast Receiver that listens for incoming SMS and searches the SMS for particular terms.  I implemented the receiver in the manifest and in a separate class from my activity.

*EDIT:*
Depending on whether or not the SMS contains a particular term I need a dialog box to pop up and in that dialog box the user will be presented with an option to go to a particular website or not go to a particular website.

If I was doing this in another language I would just have a global variable that the receiver modify and then the other method would be checking it's value to determine whether or not it needed to execute something, but I can't do that in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your title and your question match up, but if what you want is to open up a website in the browser just fire off an Intent from within your BroadcastReceiver.

If you want an explicit AlertDialog then see [AlertDialog from within BroadcastReceiver?? Can it be done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done) for some detail: you will have to use an Intent and start an Activity with the new task flag set.

EDIT: you'd do something like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, {CLASSNAME}.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);   
    }
```

Comment: so I would have to start a new activity that would handle the alert dialog?  I think that is what you are saying.  I edited my question to better reflect what I am trying to do.

Comment: If its just a browser or not, you might want to just use an Intent (like the Google Talk client does for links): that I believe you can launch without an Activity. If you want to do more complex stuff then yes, you will need to launch an Activity to handle it.

Comment: It is just a browser but the idea is that the receiver checks incoming text messages, and if a keyword is found, say CNN, then it needs to pop open an alert dialog that asks the user if they want to go to the CNN.com website.

Comment: I figured it out.  I ended up using the intent method you suggested in your answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey @ihtkwot how did you do the same? can you please tell me?

Comment: @Sandy, I followed the answer provided by Fermi.  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Work like charms !, I add your code to my SMSReceiver.java and I point out to my AlertDialogActivity.java (fill in the classname) and it works like charm !, thank you !!.

Answer (score 1):

If they allow it then any application can block the screen and can create problem to other applications. That's why I *think*, Android has not given us the leverage to use Alert window for broadcaster.  I may be wrong but I tested it once and it didn't work that time.

Alternative, You can use *TOAST*

Answer (score 0):

You want the alert dialog to appear like it opens on top of everything. Use an intent to launch a new activity with a completely clear/see through background. This technique makes the alert dialog appear like its on top of the desktop with icons in the background ;-)

Comment: do you have any samples or resources for this? I've been looking for something like this to learn how to do it for a few days and still haven't found anything that actually works.

Answer (score 0):

**if you want to open alert dialog after receiving response in onRecieve then add following code in OnRecieve, here i am alerting dialogue after clicking notification.**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainContext,HomeActivity.class).putExtra("fromNotificationClick",true); 

PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mainContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
```

**then in your homeactivity add following code in onCreate,**

```
boolean fromNotificationClick=false; 
Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();

 if(null!=extras) 
fromNotificationClick=extras.getBoolean("fromNotificationClick"); 

if(fromNotificationClick){ alert(); }
```

**Finally add code for alert method.**

```
public  void alert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this).setIcon(R.drawable.help).setTitle("Alert")
                .setMessage("Are you sure....")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Coming to help", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NO...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }).show();

    }
```