# How to modify incoming and outgoing call screen view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, popup, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

I want modify below screen according to my option.

I don't know how to access this screen.

[image]

and i need to modify this screen also

[image]

Please help me to do this.

Comment: If its a pop up window over the screen i think i can help you.

Comment: it s an default android screen pop up window only

Comment: Try [this one][1] it will help you..


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android/16080204#16080204

Comment: its not clear bro can u pls explain here

Answer (score 5):

You cannot modify default screen but instead of this you can launch your screen for that you need to use BroadCastReceiver for incoming calls

here is [the link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127130519/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/get-phone-state-when-someone-is-calling_22.html) for getting phone state in broadcast receiver

Comment: I will try it and tell you bro

Comment: yes i implemented after accept the call only it wil going to that activity

Answer (score 4):

You have to write a broad cast receiver for incoming calls the Pratiks answer have the tutorial for that.Then simply make a pop up window over the default screen. you can call the pop up class from the broadcast receiver. hope you got it:)

Comment: Ok brother i will try it and reply u

Comment: how can i call pop up class from broadcast receiver pls help me

Comment: check the broad cast receiver of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android/16080204#16080204

Comment: the screen will appearing after call got attened or rejected only... on call state ringing it will not moving the activity

Comment: Did you implement this??String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        Log.d("IncomingBroadcastReceiver: onReceive: ", state);
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)
                || state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {

Comment: yes i implemented after accept the call only it wil going to that activity

Comment: okey, let me check I will reply you tomorrow if I got anything useful.