# How to replace default incoming calling screen?

Tags: android, incoming-call

How to remove default incoming calling screen and replace it from a custom caller screen and make it default caller screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify incoming and outgoing call screen view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16098545/how-to-modify-incoming-and-outgoing-call-screen-view-in-android)

Comment: I have used floating head . so we can make touchable screen . but default incoming screen is also showing I want to hide it

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so is develop your own calling app and set it expect the user to set it as the default app for making calls.

Comment: Is it possible to remove default incoming caller screen  ? and  How ?

Comment: if you have set the new application to handle the incoming calls then it will be automatically chaged