# Android caller Id lookup from database

Tags: java, android, android-contacts

I am new in android development.
I have developed a application, in which there is personal contact directory. I can call from that directory, but if any person calling from same no which is exist in my personal directory, how could show contact info in caller id.

i need to map my contact directory information in caller id if that caller information is not exist in device contact list.

Please help.

Comment: I dont really understand your question. Is your private directory containing numbers that are not in the 'official' contact list of the device, and you want to show the information from your directory in case an 'unknown caller' is found in your directory but not the 'official' one? Say you want to add your own information display to the 'incoming call' screen?

Comment: Dear bgse, if unknown caller is found, I want to add my own information display to the incoming call screen.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out my answer here: [Provide the caller id for incoming call from my own app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870782/provide-the-caller-id-for-incoming-call-from-my-own-app/57733654#57733654)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't directly add content to the native incoming call screen, but you can put an overlay window above it to display your content.

Read the discussion in this thread regarding the overlay part:

[Pop up window over Android native incoming call screen like true caller Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android)

The answers contain all the information you require, though you will need to put the pieces together.

@Dharmik has a pretty good example for listening for the phone state (find out if a call is incoming), and @SamAdams gives a good idea about doing the overlay. My own answer builds on that of @SamAdams regarding removing the overlay screen.

Comment: Thanks bgse.
You're information is very useful.
you saved my day.

Comment: Is this still the only way to show contact info? I have a similar question, I would be very thankful if you could look it over: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32120252/android-directory-data-provider-for-phonelookup