# phonegap get caller number and add pop up on call window

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

i have an idea i want to do it .. some thing like truecaller .. i have a phonegap plguin to get the number oh the caller when the phone is ringing .. but i 'm not able to display any thing on the call screen ... and i have searched alot .. and i'm not an android guy to hack the code .. 
this is the plugin

https://github.com/madeinstefano/PhoneStateChangeListener

and what i searchd for

[Pop up window over Android native incoming call screen like true caller Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android)

Answer (score 0):

As Phonegap (and other Cordova based platforms) are use "Web View" to show UI I think it's not possible to show a browser in front of call screen.

But I searched for plugins and I found some thing to show a [little text popup](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) caleed Toast.[image]