# Display activity layer over other activity in android

Tags: android, call, overlay

I want to display a custom incoming call screen. But sometime my call screen is covered by system call screen. I want to overlay system call screen. There are so many UI component in my custom call screen. Should I use activity/fragment or any other component to display custom call screen?

Comment: Your question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android).  Have you tried the solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16117005/1953590)?

Comment: I have read this answer but I don't want 1 or 2 seconds of delay. I want logical answer.