# Masking call while making from inapp

Tags: android

Can anyone tell me on how to overwrite my apps name when a call is made from my app just how ola app does masking their name wherein the auto driver or the taxi driver to whom we have called doesn't know our name r when they call it comes under the name of ola not their name i.e the auto drivers name r taxi driver's name is it possible to implement such a feature in other apps also programatically if so can anyone tell me how to implement I search for masking of numbers and many others but unable to find .

Comment: Ever considered splitting your one sentence (which starts but doesn't end as a question) in multiple smaller readable sentences?

Comment: Please share some screen shots what actually you want.

Comment: Are you not going to award the bounty?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly to say, this just isn't entirely* possible. Here are some links detailing why:

**Incoming Calls**

Note: It is possible to display a custom GUI during an incoming call, but it is not always guaranteed that this custom GUI will be displayed first.

[Pop up window over Android native incoming call screen like true caller Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15683952/pop-up-window-over-android-native-incoming-call-screen-like-true-caller-android?rq=1)

**Outgoing Calls**

Note: it is possible to override the outgoing number called, but not to mask it

http://androidlabs.org/short-experiments/broadcast-receivers/process-outgoing-calls/

Ola App uses a backend telephony system, where taxi cab requests are sent to a phone center(owned by Ola).

Taxi cab drivers register and install a client app that automatically handles calls(and numbers).

This way the identity of the taxi cab driver and the rider can be masked.

When a taxi driver needs to call a rider, that call is passed through Ola's telephony system as well. This is why the phone number displayed on the rider's phone is different from the driver's real number.

Hope that helps...