# Alert dialog in child class not working in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, builder

`AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());`

OR

`AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);`

OR

`AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();`

Any of above code does not work if I write this code in any child class of main activity class, application get crashed.

If I write this code under onCreate method, then it works fine.

Comment: Show your code and logcat.

Comment: If there is a crash, at least make the effort to post the logcat.

Comment: In which class/function is it called?

Comment: @Piyush: I am using a class which returns the list of products..........class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {}

Comment: Guyz... My problem is very much similar to the problem which is mentioned in following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059545/show-dialog-alert-from-a-non-activity-class-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Giving an Activity should work:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this).create();
```

Comment: @RajeshJaiswal then define better "does not work" please (in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code :

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
                            }
                        });
```