# Using context inside class extending BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog, android-alarms

When an alarm in android goes off, I want to create an AlertDialog. Also, I want to create a notification, depending on which option the user clicks in the radio buttons on the dialog.
The problem arises when I try to use `context` or `getApplicationContext()`.

This is my code:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
{
    final CharSequence[] items = {" I'm taking the dose now! "," Remind again in ten minutes. "," Ignore for now. "};
    String doseName = intent.getStringExtra("doseName");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Take medicine: " + doseName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("It's time for your medicine.");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            switch(item)
            {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Good.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder set in ten minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent service1 = new Intent(context, DoseAlarmService.class);
                service1.putExtra("doseName", doseName);
                context.startService(service1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    levelDialog = builder.create();
    levelDialog.show();
}
```

I've tried using `getApplicationContext` instead of `context` inside the switch case, but this is the exact error i get:

```
The method getApplicationContext() is undefined for the type new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}
```

Any suggestions of how to go forward?

**EDIT:**

Till now, these are what i've tried:

```
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
{
        ctx = context;
    final CharSequence[] items = {" I'm taking the dose now! "," Remind again in ten minutes. "," Ignore for now. "};
    String doseName = intent.getStringExtra("doseName");
    Toast.makeText(ctx, "Take medicine: " + doseName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx.getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("It's time for your medicine.");
    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            switch(item)
            {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Good.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Reminder set in ten minutes.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Intent service1 = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), DoseAlarmService.class);
                service1.putExtra("doseName", doseName);
                ctx.startService(service1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    levelDialog = builder.create();
    levelDialog.show();
}
```

Also, instead of using `ctx`, i'v directly used `context.getApplicationContext()` and checked. It doesn't work.

Also, when I comment out all the problematic areas and just run to verify that the dialog box turns up, I get this exception:

```
07-23 13:26:21.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1756): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.dosemanager.ui.DoseAlarmReceiever: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

Please help!

Comment: you can use context.getApplicationContext().

Comment: Now, this is another problem. You can't show dialog without activity. Create new activity and show dialog there.

Comment: try to use 'Activity cxt = (Activity)context;' and use cxt as your context

Answer (score 3):

Hm, you already have your context - it's `onReceive()`'s parameter. You don't need to use `getApplicationContext()`.

EDIT: You can't use context in switch case, because context is defined in Receiver class and you are trying to use it in `onClickListener` class. 
I suggest this:

```
  public class %YOUR_RECEIVER_CLASS% {
       private Context context;
       public onReceive(Context context, ...) {
            this.context = context;
       }
  }
```

NOW you can use context everywhere

Comment: he can use context in onClickListener because his contex is 'final'

Comment: LOL no. Is it final or not, but it's only a parameter of method, but not a member of class.

Comment: there is no need for context to be a member o class dude... onClickListener just need to know that Context will not change, so he use 'final' it not looks well but it is correct

Comment: Do You know about scopes? Method onClick in his unnamed child of onClickListener do not have access to the onReceive's scope. SO, he can't access context that is parameter of onReceive.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to start an alert dialog from a broadcast receiver, which is not allowed. Check this out:

[show an alert dialog in broadcast receiver after a system reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

use getBaseContext() instead of getApplicationContext()

example BroadcastReceiver::

```
 @Override
     public void onCreate() 
     {        
         Toast.makeText(this, "SmsSenderService()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
         {
                public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
               {
                 switch (getResultCode())
                 {
                  case Activity.RESULT_OK:                  

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        

                    break;

                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Oh dear god, you are trying to fire getBaseContext method IN THE ONCLICKLISTENER. OnClickListener DO NOT HAVE SUCH METHOD. YOU NEED to push context to your onClickListener OR make Context a field in your Receiver AS I SAID. How many times do I need to repeat that? Do not listen to whose who suggest using getContext or getBaseContext or something else, because they know nothin