# Old activity context show in background of DialogActivity instead of HomeScreen

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-context

I have set a broadcast receiver which starts a new `DialogActivity`. The problem faced is that whenever the `BroadcastReceiver` receives a broadcast, the `DialogActivity` is shown but in the background instead of homescreen, the activity from where I have registered Receiver is shown and over it `DialogActivity` is shown.

Following is the code :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent i) {
Intent i1 = new Intent(arg0,AlarmDialog.class);
i1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
arg0.startActivity(i1);     //this leads to background as the old activity where I have initially registered the broadcast
}
```

Also if the context from which I am starting the `DialogActivity` i.e `arg0` here is finished then the app force closes as the `DialogActivity` requires the context.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, Broadcast Receivers should not show any dialogues. They should show notification, which when click on can take display an activity with a dialog. However, if you'd like to show a dialog without any activity there's a description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8766864/2519822).