# Get current Activity with Android

Tags: java, android

I have a method that scans the position and gets called on every activity I have, everytime an actions trigger I need to show an alertDialog, this is the code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mMainActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage("test")
                           .setCancelable(false)
                           .setPositiveButton("go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                   Intent intent = new Intent(mMainActivity.this,LocationDetails.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("placeId",1);
                                    startActivity(intent);

                               }
                           })
                           .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                    dialog.cancel();
                               }
                           });
                        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                        alert.show();
```

But How can I create the alert on the current activity? Because now it only gets created on `AlertDialog.Builder(mMainActivity.this);`

Answer (score 1):

Have this `AlertDialog` logic in a public class and make call using a method with passing context .

For example:

```
showAlert(youractivitycontext);
```

Use the `Context` as your current activity.

Answer (score 1):

You have various options... what you have to know:

> You can show AlertDialogs from Activity only

You have various options

- Pass your activity instance as parameter in constructor of other classes... then you can call activity from everywhere
- Use notifications (class does not need to be an Activity)
- [Check this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot) otherwise

Answer (score 0):

```
create class vis static method in vich you transfer "link" yours activitis 
for example from MainActivity call :
DialogUtils.createSomeDialog(MainActivity.this); 
or from SecondActivity:
DialogUtils.createSomeDialog(SecondActivity.this);


    public class DialogUtils
{
    public static void createSomeDialog(final Context context){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setMessage("test")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(context,LocationDetails.class);
                        intent.putExtra("placeId",1);
                        context.startActivity(intent);

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```