# Showing Dialog from Retrofit's Interceptor

Tags: android, dialog, retrofit, interceptor

I am trying to display a dialog from Retrofit interceptor when few parameters are not satisfied. 
But I got `android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?` exception when trying to show dialog.

Here is my code.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShieldSquare.applicationContext)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Are you sure to Exit")
            .setMessage("Exiting will call finish() method")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            })
            //set negative button
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    //set what should happen when negative button is clicked
                    Toast.makeText(ShieldSquare.applicationContext,
                            "Nothing Happened", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            alertDialog.create().show();
        }
    };

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(runnable);
```

Above code running on Interceptor before Retrofit's chain is proceed.

`ssResponse = chain.proceed(originalRequest);`

Comment: alert dialog not show into retrofit  Interceptor. it show only activity or fragment. when you call api that time show alert dialog.

Comment: @AndroidTeam Thanks. I am developing an SDK for android which will detect misuse of application and stops api calls followed by showing a dialog. How such thing can be implemented in context of Retrofit interceptor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, we only display dialogs from activities, so the context `ShieldSquare.applicationContext` is unable to show the `AlertDialog`.

There are two methods which can meet your needs:

**First one**, use a special permission `android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.
Before your `alertDialog.show();`, add:

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

And add the permission below to the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Then you can use `ShieldSquare.applicationContext` for dialog builder.

**Second one**, you can update your `ShieldSquare.applicationContext` to the most recent activity, then the `ShieldSquare.applicationContext` will always be an activity's context:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ShieldSquare.applicationContext = this;
    }
}
```

And I found a few approaches about using `BroadcastReceiver` to show the dialogs, you can also have a look, see the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot) and this [blog post](https://medium.com/@nhancv/android-show-dialog-without-activity-context-94661d48400f).

Comment: thanks Hong Duan. I will try suggestions made by you and come back.