# AlertDialog show = new AlertDialog.Builder(this) is Undefined

Tags: java, android, sms, this, android-alertdialog

The app intercepts sms messages and displays a `Dialog` of the message.

However I am unable to get my `Dialog` error resolved in my `Test` class. What am I doing wrong?

(I've also included my other 2 files).

ERROR shown in Eclipse: `AlertDialog.Builder(Test) is undefined`

---

**test.java**

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;

public class Test extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";            
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                str += " :";
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                str += "\n";                  
            }

            AlertDialog show = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Message")
            .setMessage(str)
            .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
            .show();
    }                         
}
```

}

---

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
    </uses-permission>
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Hello"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hello" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".test"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name=
                    "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

---

**hello.java**

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Hello extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_hello, menu);
        return true;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("Message")
    .setMessage(str)
    .setNeutralButton("OK", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
```

Instead of:

```
AlertDialog show = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Message")
    .setMessage(str)
    .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
    .show();
```

You have to create an instance of an `AlertDialog.Builder` first. Then you can build the `Dialog` with `builder.create()`. Then you can show the `Dialog` with `.show()`.

Comment: I still get the error:  AlertDialog.Builder(Test) is undefined

Comment: I am new to android development, but I have used visual studio to develop this kind software before.In Visual Studio, we just call the function, no need to create the resource, is it the same in android development?

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to android but found that sometimes you cant create an alert inside a class that is not an activity.
you should then get the context directly and create the alert.

```
public void showAlert(String message){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Here is a message message from my activity")
        .setMessage(message)
        .setNeutralButton("OK", null);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use dialog on BroadcastReceiver, 
so instead you better call an activity for the dialog box from the BroadcastReceiver,

add this code in your onReceive function :

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    Intent i = new Intent(context, {CLASSNAME}.class); 
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

fill the {CLASSNAME} with the dialog activity, heres my dialog activity :

```
package com.example.mbanking;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


// ALERT DIALOG
// Sources : http://techblogon.com/alert-dialog-with-edittext-in-android-example-with-source-code/

public class AlertDialogActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder
        .setTitle("Test")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
}
```

where I got the answer ?, here : [How do you use an alert dialog box in a broadcast receiver in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172088/how-do-you-use-an-alert-dialog-box-in-a-broadcast-receiver-in-android)
thanks to Femi !!, I just spread the news :D,

greetings from Indonesia.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code instead. I tested it.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ShowMessage();
        }
    });
}

protected void ShowMessage(){
    AlertDialog show = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Message")
            .setMessage("khguh")
            .setNeutralButton("OK", null)
            .show();
}
```