# How to add AlertDialog in broadcast receiver class in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, sms

I'm developing one sms application. In that once the SMS comes to inbox it should display some alert.
I want to add alert in the following code. Is it possible?

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if(null != bundle)
        {

            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            byte[] data = null;

            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                


            }


        }
        }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4844031/741249

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `Activity` in your application and start `Activity` from your `BroadcastReceiver`

and now launch `AlertDialog` within `onCreate` method  of `Activity`

create `style.xml` inside `res/values` folder and put this inside it

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

    </style>
```

make `Activty` Transparent by putting `android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"` as a attribute of `Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file so only `AlertDialog` will be shown.

Comment: this alert will it display even the application is not running in the foreground?

Comment: yes it will be displayed. whenever you start your activity from from your `BroadcastReceiver` . if you write the code of `AlertDialog` within `onCreate()` method of `Activity` started from `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: ok. Is it possible to check the receiving part of application using emulator(application has port number) ?

Comment: if you are using `BroadcastReceiver` to receive SMS, you can send SMS to emulator using DDMS to check the receiving part of application .

Comment: Yes, i'm using BroadcastReceiver to receive the messages. But the messages should come to the application inbox(i.e., to specific port) not to the native inbox. Is it possible to check this in emulator?

Comment: I think There is no way to send sms on specific port using DDMS. send sms normally using DDMS. and see what happens your BroadcastReceiver receives that SMS or not.

Comment: @Ravi1187342 how to display the alert dialog after calling the broadcast receiver intent?

Comment: @ AndroidOptimist  start activity with transparent background and display Alert dialog inside activity's oncreat() or on resume() method, in this case only alert dialog will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i have understood, u are not able to launch activity from a broadcast receiver. If that is the case, this will help you:

```
  Intent i=new Intent(context,ActivityName.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

and "how to show AlertDialog", following Ravi's answer is the best thing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Call new activity set dialog theme and called from onReceive method of Broadcast Receiver..

Answer (score 0):

You should use a Notification Manager:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Specifically Google say (their emphasis):

> A background service **should never** launch an activity on its own in order to receive user interaction. The service should instead create a status bar notification that will launch the activity when selected by the user.

You're talking about a BroadcastReceiver rather than a service, but I suspect it still applies.