# Custom AlertDialog with Themed Dialog crashing when added View.onClickListener

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I am using an Activity with a Theme.Dialog to do my AlertDialog as i'm trying to use this dialog inside a BroadcastReceiver but when i added a OnClickListener the application crashes everytime it launches.

Code:

```
package nyp.android.project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PasswordDialog extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "Logging Activity";
    //Context context;   
    Button login;
    EditText inputPassword;

    private static final int MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //this.context = context;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.password_dialog);

        //SharedPreferences passwdfile = context.getSharedPreferences(    
        //        PhoneFinder.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, 0); 

        //String correctSHA1 = passwdfile.getString(PhoneFinder.PASSWORD_PREF_KEY, null);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
              Toast.makeText(PasswordDialog.this, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        }

    }
```

Logcat:

```
07-25 12:27:30.354: D/AndroidRuntime(570): Shutting down VM
07-25 12:27:30.354: W/dalvikvm(570): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nyp.android.project/nyp.android.project.PasswordDialog}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at nyp.android.project.PasswordDialog.onCreate(PasswordDialog.java:38)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-25 12:27:30.364: E/AndroidRuntime(570):  ... 11 more
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >


        <!--  Password Label -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:text="Password" />
        <!--  Password TextField -->

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:password="true" />

        <!--  Login Button -->        
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:text="Login" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Because, you're assigning your global context to the same global context with null value. One you've to give like `this.context = this` or you've to remove all the `context` and use `PasswordDialog.this` instead of `context`

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any effect, app still crashes with same errors.

Comment: Show us your `broadcastReceiver` class?

Comment: See the Exception. Its `ClassCastException` Post your `xml` code here

Comment: Posted XML, and i haven't use this activity in my broadcastreceiver yet so that wouldnt be the problem, just trying to code this out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
```

see above line of error,**You are try to refrences EditText ,not Button...**

Answer (score 0):

This because of you're identifying `EditText`'s id as `Button`'s id. So try to do like below -

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
```

This is the exact place where the error comes.

Answer (score 0):

An AlertDialog can not be generated from BroadcastReceiver class, please see

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done)

Comment: please read, i'm not doing an alertdialog. I am intenting a new activity from BroadcastReceiver with a Theme.Dialog

Comment: Sorry dythe, my bad. I was having problems with showing AlertDialog from BroadcastReceiver just a couple of days back, hence I quickly went into the answer. Sorry.