# Bad window token, you cannot show a dialog before an Activity is created or after it's hidden exception in broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

i am creating material dialog inside the onReceive method.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{

new MaterialDialog.Builder(context)
                            .title(sender).content(m).positiveText("C").negativeText("Cl").onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog materialDialog, @NonNull DialogAction dialogAction) {
                            copyToClipboard(m);
                        }
                    }).onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog materialDialog, @NonNull DialogAction dialogAction) {

                        }
                    }).show();
 }
```

I am getting the below exception

```
 Caused by: com.afollestad.materialdialogs.MaterialDialog$DialogException: Bad window token, you cannot show a dialog before an Activity is created or after it's hidden.
```

Comment: Add the code of your ownReceive method here as well. Dialog should always be shown on a UI thread. On Receive is usually in BG thread

Comment: where have you written this code, i mean where in activity or fragment?

Comment: Question edited

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly open a dialog from a Broadcast receiver as its a UI centric activity. The best way for you to do that would be to design a custom activity with a transparent background, register it as the Broadcast Receiver and then show the Alert dialog there.

Refer to [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844031/alertdialog-from-within-broadcastreceiver-can-it-be-done)